# Disable custom connected app from profile

Tags: profile, connected-apps, oauth

I have a custom connected app that is used for OAuth purposes (outside of Salesforce). Therefore I don't need it to appear in the app launcher, unfortunately I see no way to remove it, at least for all non-admin profiles.

I expected under ***Settings -> Profiles -> MyProfile*** under the "Connected App Access" section I could remove it, which I have, but unfortunately when I login under users with that profile it still appears.

Am I missing something? I don't see any other options to accomplish this. I am also having the same issue with certain managed package, (i.e. Conga); hopefully the answer will apply to both scenarios.

> **Update:**

I attempted the instructions [here](https://help.screensteps.com/m/salesforce/l/149551-assign-user-profiles-to-your-connected-app-in-salesforce) but unfortunately at the "Select Manage Profiles
" step don't have the profile section it claims should be there (see screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: Do you mind checking this link? - https://help.screensteps.com/m/salesforce/l/149551-assign-user-profiles-to-your-connected-app-in-salesforce

Comment: I attempted this before but did not have the same options available to me, update OP accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Settings-> Manage Connected Appss -> select your app

Then, Click on **Edit Policies**

Ensure you have selected **Admin approved users are pre-authorized** option in Permitted Users field under **OAuth Policies**

The profile section would be visible now !!!!!